# What conditions on $A$ guarantee that $x\geq 0$ iff $Ax\geq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, what conditions on $A$ guarantee that $x\geq 0$ iff $Ax\geq 0$?  Here, $x\geq 0$ denotes pointwise inequality (nonnegative orthant.)  This is true if $A$ is diagonal and the diagonal elements are all positive.  I'm curious if there's a more general condition.

Comment: My guess, off the top of my head: if and only if $A$ is like a permutation matrix except with positive entries allowed instead of 1's.  (Outline of possible proof: $A$ must preserve the 1-dimensional faces of the cone $[0,\infty)^m$, so $A$ must permute the axes $[0, \infty) \cdot e_1, \ldots, [0, \infty) \cdot e_m$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the following facts:

1. Since $\mathbf e_i\succeq\mathbf0$, $A\mathbf e_i\succeq\mathbf0$; so $A\ge0$ (all entries are non-negative).
2. $A$ is non-singular because $\mathbf x\in\ker A\implies-\mathbf x\in \ker A$.
3. $A(A^{-1}\mathbf e_i) = \mathbf e_i\succeq\mathbf0 \implies A^{-1}\mathbf e_i\succeq\mathbf0$. Therefore, $A^{-1}\ge0$.
4. Put $A=(a_{ij})$ and $A^{-1}=(b_{ij})$. For $i\ne j$, we have
   $$
     \sum_{h=1}^n a_{ih}b_{hj} = 0.
   $$
   Therefore, $a_{ih}b_{hj}=0$ for all $i,j,h$. Thus, for every $h$ there is one, and only one, $i$ such that $a_{ih}\ne0$: should $a_{i'h}\ne0$, then $b_{hj}=0$ for all $j$ $\to\leftarrow$.

Thus, $A$ is a permutation of the identity with rows multiplied by positive scalars.